# Angular Typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead) - getting latitude/longitude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I am having trouble using the angular typehead

There is an example [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) that uses angular typehead to create an auto-complete using the Google maps API.

My problem is that when I click on the results within the typehead my model is then populated with the `item.formatted_address` data.  How can I click on the formatted address and then populate with the lat/longitude data

```
// Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously   
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
  return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params: {
      address: val,
      sensor: false
    }
  }).then(function(res){
    var addresses = [];
    angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
      addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
    });
    return addresses;
  });   };

<h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
<pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

Comment: My intent is to just have the user select the pretty adress and the assign my model an object containing the formatted and lat/long data

Comment: I know how to use angular-ui typeahead very well, but I really don't understand your question.  Besides your code is just a paste of the documentation.

Comment: When I click on the drop down list my model is being populated with a formatted address string- I want to use this setup to pupulate my model with an object comprised of  the formatted string an the Latitude and Longitude

Comment: Righht now if I click the drop down list then the model becomes populated with the formatted address string. Instead I want the model to be  : {formattedString "123 fake street", "lat":34, lng :12}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of achieving the desired result, below I'm presenting one of the possibilities. But before diving into the solution it is important to notice that the typeahead uses similar syntax to the AngularJS built-in `select` directive and as such you can use expressions in all the parts of the `typeahead` attribute. Given this you could write:

```
typeahead="address as address.formatted_address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"
```

and change your XHR success callback to:

```
.then(function(response){
      return response.data.results.map(function(item){
        return {
          location: item.geometry.location,
          formatted_address: item.formatted_address
        }
      });
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/4PwaFaeIOeIDRCsvuidn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of the model of the item returned by the google map API :

```
Model: {
  "address_components": [
//Not useful here   
[...]
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address": "E, Santiago de Cuba, Cuba",
  "geometry": {
    "bounds": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 20.0076143,
        "lng": -75.8325446
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 20.0069908,
        "lng": -75.8372035
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "lat": 20.007418,
      "lng": -75.8349013
    },
    "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
    "viewport": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 20.00865153029151,
        "lng": -75.8325446
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 20.0059535697085,
        "lng": -75.8372035
      }
    }
  },
  "types": [
    "route"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, in their example angular-ui selects `item.formatted_adress`

You want latitude and longitude information, so that would be `item.location`.

Getting it straight from the typeahead would involve manipulating JSON and finding the correct data structure, so you may want to start by letting the user select the location as it exists in the documentation example, and then asking the maps API more details about that particular location, thus retrieving location data.